# Dynamically change img ng-repeat using firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase-realtime-database

I have a page where a teacher can select a class (of school students). Then the teacher can create groups of students from this class by dragging avatars of the students.

I have a drop down list of classes and a `div` filled with avatars of the students.

The HTML:

```
<select name="chosenClass" onchange="chooseClass(this.value)">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in techerClasses">{{key}}</option>
</select>
...
<div id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="groupDiv">
    <img ng-repeat="(key, value) in classStudents"  id={{key}} src="http://placehold.it/30x30/{{value}}" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>
```

The controller code:

```
chooseClass = function (classInfo) {
    if (classInfo > 0){
        $rootScope.classesRef.child(classInfo).on('value', function (dataSnapshot){
            $rootScope.classStudents = dataSnapshot.val().members;
        });
    }
}
```

1. If I add data manually to the `$rootScope.classStudents` before
   the page loads the avatars will show correctly.
2. `console.log($rootScope.classStudents)` after
   `$rootScope.classStudents = dataSnapshot.val().members;` confirms
   that the right data is in there.
3. But the avatars are not showing.
4. If I click "back" in the browser and then "forward" - the avatars
   will show. This leads me to think that I need something that will
   tell the `<img ng-repeat...` to refresh?

Comment: use `ng-src' instead of src in img tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a $rootScope.$apply as you've done something outside of angular:

```
chooseClass = function (classInfo) {
    if (classInfo > 0){
        $rootScope.classesRef.child(classInfo).on('value', function (dataSnapshot){
            $rootScope.classStudents = dataSnapshot.val().members;
            $rootScope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively look into using `$firebaseArray`:

```
chooseClass = function (classInfo) {
    if (classInfo > 0){
        $rootScope.classStudents = $firebaseArray($rootScope.classesRef.child(classInfo).child('members'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set `src="http://placehold.it/30x30/{{value}}"` to `ng-src="http://placehold.it/30x30/{{value}}"` to add the src attribute to the digest.

Also `$rootScope.$apply` or `$timeout(angular.noop)` if you need a "save digest"